# How to plot a column after deleting a few rows from the data frame?

Tags: r, plot, time-series, xts

Language: R
Data: from "Yahoo! Finance"

I am trying to delete 100 rows of data from a stock price dataset and then I want to plot the "Close" column. I expect to see a straight line inside the graph(for the missing values area). When I am running the following code, I get the below error message.

**CODE**:

```
library(quantmod)
alt.data.AMZN <- getSymbols("AMZN", from="2010-12-31", to="2013-12-31", auto.assign = FALSE)
class(alt.data.AMZN)
head(alt.data.AMZN)
plot(alt.data.AMZN$AMZN.Close)
#Deleting a few rows of data from the xts object.
data.missing <- alt.data.AMZN[c(-400:-500),]
head(data.missing)
plot(data.missing$AMZN.close) #This is where I get the error
```

> Error message**:
> Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
> 2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
> 3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
> 4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: You have a typo in there. Try `plot(data.missing$AMZN.Close)`. Also why you use `alt.data.AMZN` when you have stored data in `data.AMZN` ?

Comment: Hi Ronak, sorry for the typo. I checked my code and I had stored it as alt.data.AMZN only. I had deleted the "alt" by mistake while posting the question and while formatting it on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the rows you could set them equal to NA. Then the plot won't show any values for the missing values. If you want a straight line, you can run `na.locf` on the resulting xts and you'll end up with a straight line for the missing values.

```
data.missing <- alt.data.AMZN
data.missing[c(400:500), ] <- NA
plot(data.missing$AMZN.Close)
```

[image: plot with missing values]

```
data.missing2 <- na.locf(data.missing)
plot(data.missing2$AMZN.Close)
```

[image: plot with a straight line]